# How can I prevent graphical dialog that says the file has changed since visited or saved?

Tags: gui-emacs

I don't want the graphical popup, but I'm ok with a mode-line question.

Is there any way to disable these graphical popups forever?;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have just searched the manual. Check out [chapter 22.18 Using Dialog Boxes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dialog-Boxes.html) of the Emacs manual which states “To disable the use of dialog boxes, change the variable `use-dialog-box` to `nil`.”; hopefully you know how to do that.

Comment: Yes, I find it as first result if I search for it now, using the correct terms, with multiple results, so yes, sorry;). It's just an unfortunate series of events that led me to post this question;). Thanks.